# Embed two D3 charts simultaneously on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, embed

I have two charts which I want to embed on a single page, below I've provided the target page link on which I want to embed both charts. Both the charts are currently featured on separate pages, and I've mentioned the URL for them as well.
Target page: http://staging.blackrockblog.com/2015/10/26/how-the-world-retires/

Chart1 page: https://digitalxlabs.com/d3-charts/retirement-transition-graph.php

Chart2 page: https://digitalxlabs.com/animated-banners/retirement-map.php

Note: Chart 2 has already been implemented, but I'm having issues in adding Chart 1. It needs to be featured in place of the animated GIF image featured on the target page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unable to see the chart pages -- username and password required.

Also, i'd be helpful to know what issues you've encountered. Putting two charts on the same page should be straight forward.

Comment: @TomP Here are the credentials:
Username: DXLdemo
Password: View@098#